# Locking with asynchronous httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

I have an object that downloads a file from a server, saves it into Isolated Storage asynchronously and provides a GetData method to retrieve the data. Would I use a

```
IsolatedStorageFile storageObj; //initialized in the constructor

lock(storageObj)
{
   //save code
}
```

In the response and

```
lock(storageObj)
{
   //load code
}
```

In the GetData method?

Edit: I'll give some context here.
The app (for Windows Phone) needs to download and cache multiple files from a server, so I've created a type that takes 2 strings (a uri and a filename), sends out for data from the given uri, and saves it. The same object also has the get data method. Here's the code (simplified a bit)

```
public class ServerData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public readonly string ServerUri;
    public readonly string Filename;
    IsolatedStorageFile appStorage;

    DownloadState _downloadStatus = DownloadState.NotStarted;
    public DownloadState DownloadStatus
    {
        protected set
        {
            if (_downloadStatus == value) return;
            _downloadStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DownloadStatus"));
        }
        get { return _downloadStatus; }
    }

    public ServerData(string serverUri, string filename)
    {
        ServerUri = serverUri;
        Filename = filename;
        appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, args);
    }

    public void RequestDataFromServer()
    {
        DownloadStatus = DownloadState.Downloading;
   //this first bit adds a random unused query to the Uri, 
   //so Silverlight won't cache the request
        Random rand = new Random();
        StringBuilder uriText = new StringBuilder(ServerUri);
        uriText.AppendFormat("?YouHaveGotToBeKiddingMeHack={0}", 
                             rand.Next().ToString());
        Uri uri = new Uri(uriText.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
        HttpWebRequest serverRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        ServerRequestUpdateState serverState = new ServerRequestUpdateState();
        serverState.AsyncRequest = serverRequest;
        serverRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestResponse),
            serverState);
    }

    void RequestResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        var serverState = (ServerRequestUpdateState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        var serverRequest = (HttpWebRequest)serverState.AsyncRequest;
        Stream serverStream;
        try
        {
            // end the async request
            serverState.AsyncResponse = 
                (HttpWebResponse)serverRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
            serverStream = serverState.AsyncResponse.GetResponseStream();
            Save(serverStream);
            serverStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            DownloadStatus = DownloadState.Error;
        }

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            DownloadStatus = DownloadState.FileReady;
        });
    }

    void Save(Stream streamToSave)
    {
        StreamReader reader = null;
        IsolatedStorageFileStream file;
        StreamWriter writer = null;
        reader = new StreamReader(streamToSave);

        lock (appStorage)
        {
            file = appStorage.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Create);
            writer = new StreamWriter(file);
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            reader.Dispose();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public XDocument GetData()
    {
        XDocument xml = null;
        lock(appStorage)
        {
            if (appStorage.FileExists(Filename))
            {
                var file = appStorage.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Open);
                xml = XDocument.Load(file);
                file.Dispose();
            }
        }
        if (xml != null)
            return xml;
        else return new XDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: if this is the case why not do it synchronously?

Comment: That would block the ui thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide an awful lot of context, and with the amount of information given people could be inclined to simply tell you yes, maybe with small, but pertinent additions.

Practice generally sees locking occur on an instance of a dedicated `object`, being sure to stay away from locking on `this` since you lock the whole instance of the current object down, which is scarcely, if ever the intent - but, in your case, we don't rightly know to the fullest extent, however, I hardly think locking your storage instance is the way to go.

Also, since you mention client and server interaction, it isn't as straight forward.

Depending on the load and many other factors, you might want to provide many reads of the file from the server yet only a single write at any one time on the client that is downloading; for this purpose I would recommend using the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class, which exposes `TryEnterReadLock`, `TryEnterWriteLock` and corresponding release methods.

For more detailed information on this class see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Also, remember to use `try`, `catch` and `finally` when coding within the scope of a lock, always releasing the lock in the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll expand my question.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget, there is no writing to the server in this app, arguments for the data requested is strictly in the uri.

Comment: Sadly, ReaderWriterLockSlim isn't in Silverlight.

Comment: @Chris: Take a look into `Monitor` in that case - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Okay, so the difference between Monitor.Enter(Object) and Monitor.TryEnter(Object) is that the TryEnter won't block? Hmm. You mean if I have several threads trying to read the file at the same time, and they block each other with a lock(Object) statement. Now the question is how to handle a TryEnter() == false situation. Hmm...

Comment: My current plan is to ensure that all file access is done on BackgroundWorkers, which would be okay to block, as long as deadlock doesn't happen. Generally speaking, only holding one lock at a time should prevent this from happening. (I've switched from using the appData object to a private object created for that purpose. I mixed up private object with a private _reference_ to an object.

Answer (score 0):

What class contains this code? That matters as it's important if it's being created more than once. If it's created once in the process' lifetime, you can do this, if not you should lock a *static* object instance.

I believe though that it's good practice to create a separate object that's used only for the purpose of locking, I've forgotten why. E.g.:

```
IsolatedStorageFile storageObj; //initialized in the constructor
(static) storageObjLock = new object();
...
// in some method
lock(storageObjLock)
{
   //save code 
}
```